# UIScrollView set contentInset.top don't push the content view down?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a `UIScrollView` embed in `UINavigationController`. I set `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `false`.

In the `UIScrollView` I created two labels. Label jack is on top right below the navigation bar. 
[image]

In the `viewDidAppear` I set `scrollView.contentInset.top = 100`. 
[image]

I suppose `contentInset` will push the label jack down. But It doesn't. The label is still right below the navigation bar just like storyboard showed.

What's the problem of my code? Something I may miss?

Comment: put your code as code don't as Image please

Comment: the same code as you post, but I got the right result. as @user1000's answer:  set scrollView's content inset in viewDidLoad method will make "automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets" work. but content inset works correctly in either way. so weird :(

Comment: @vg0x00 It's really weird. It automatically sets `contentOffset` for me just like `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets  = true` doing the trick

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add

```
scrollView.contentInset.top = 100
```

in `viewDidLoad` instead of `viewDidAppear`

Comment: Yes, It works in `viewDidLoad`. I am wondering why `viewDidLoad`, not `viewDidAppear`?